# Only a part of the page loads on first load

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reason only the header of this [page](http://goo.gl/OPr5D) loads on first load. On subsequent page loads, the entire page content is loaded. What may be the problem for such an issue ?

Comment: It loads just fine for me in Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: It opened quite well here all the times, including the first one ... What browser have you used ?? I saw few jquery´s in your code... maybe is just a misscompatibility in your browser !

Comment: Fine in Firefox... Are you using Netscape? :p

Comment: Fine in Chrome and IE9. Do you have any plugins (like adblock)?

Comment: same here... first load (only header and menu) - reload or second load whole page... i try to figure it out (FF 8 on mac here)

Comment: no plugins used... the "first load" on the latest Chrome and Safari loads only header

Comment: i testes now (mac) FF8.0.1, Chrome 15.0.x and Safari 5.1.1. Your problem only appering in FF8 here and only for the first load. After deactivating cache and reload the probem is not appearing again. Sorry cant help anymore :(

Comment: Tested on Firefox 8.0 on Widnows 7, Getting the same problem as OP. Seems really odd to me, Gonna have a quick look over it I'm taking a wild guess and saying it's something to do with the Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Your loading a lot of Javascript files. Try to see if some of theese maybe are the problem by taking them out and test again.

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be an unclosed element

see validation [here](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://next.noca.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

not to be rude but you are also using obsolete tags

Comment: You are probably right, i will try resolving these errors and try again.

Comment: the `&` in your links should be replaced by `&amp;` and the `<input>` should not be in an `<a>`